# Travelling to France while waiting for residence permit renewal in Italy

Tags: visas, schengen, flixbus

I am going to travel to Nice from Turin with Flixbus. If I have the postal receipt for the permesso application, italian carta identita, expired VISA and invitation for a scientific activity in France, can I still travel?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: Yes. You cannot travel in this situation. They said you must have a valid permit.

Answer (score 1):

As per the OP's result - it is not possible to travel in this situation.

Travellers must be in possession of a valid travel permit/visa/permission to cross border.